# Change position of UI GameObjects (RectTransform) in scroll bar pannel

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, scrollbar, transform

So with my [panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLos2.png) I have a 'compact view' switch which i would like to make everything go compact! I have the anchored positions (from top center) for all the Mods in both compact and spaced view mode. Is there any way to easily switch between them taking into acount that it is has a scrollbar? I have already tried transforming the positions and timesing it by scrollbar value but no luck so far! Any help will be much appreciated :)

Comment: What are the results you are currently getting in compact view?

Comment: It doesn't do anything at the moment i'm trying to work out how it's even possible?

Comment: Can you add a snippet of your current code which sets the positions but doesn't do anything?

Comment: It isn't code, I only have the anchored positions for where each thing should be but `recttransform.transform.position = new vector3(x, y, 0) ` or something along those lines (thats from my memory). That peice of code seems to do the position to the pixels on screen instead of the anchored position relative to scrollbar value and different resolutions (which can stretch the panels). I am asking whether there is an easy way to change the anchored position to make a compact view. Thanks!

Comment: You can modify rectTransform.anchoredPosition and rectTransform.sizeDelta.

Comment: How can you modify recttransform.anchoredPosition.y because whenever I have tried it always gives me an error the value can only returned and cannot be changed as it is not a variable

Comment: rectTransform.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(rectTransform.anchoredPosition.x, yValue);

Comment: Thanks, worked , can u put this as an answer so i can accept it if anyone else has the same problem (Also, worked best when was anchored from top middle which might be worth a mention)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In UI system, change anchored positions using **rectTransform.anchoredPosition** instead of rectTransform.position. In Screen Space - Overlay mode, both may achieve the same thing in some circumstances but in other canvas render modes or inside a scroll view, changing position will likely result in an incorrect anchored position.

To change the RectTransform's dimensions, use **rectTransform.sizeDelta**. For sizeDelta to actually represent the RectTransform's dimensions, RectTransform's *anchorMin* and *anchorMax* values must be the same. Otherwise, sizeDelta has different meanings like 'the distance from the split anchors'.

Comment: Code for positioning inside scrollbar: `rectTransform.anchoredPosition = new Vector2(rectTransform.anchoredPosition.x, yValue);` and to change size of panels: `rectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(width, height);`